# OpenGL missing functions?

Tags: java, opengl

I have been following the tutorial from Java Gaming Org (can't paste link, max 2 for rep) and for some reason, can't get this class to work.

Their copy: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?action=pastebin&hex=aad2e5d9f6f

My copy: http://pastebin.com/VMPXAGmn

Their copy works, mine doesn't. Essentially, I think I'm just missing a line or putting the wrong value in. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should write some code, not links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

In `glOrtho()` you have zNear set to `-1` while it should be `1`.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, that was annoying.